# Gatsbyjs Local HTTPS getting browser security errors

Tags: https, localhost, gatsby

I'm trying to set up local `https` with [gatsbyjs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/).  I followed [gatsby's instructions](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/local-https/#usage-automatic-https) including setting up `Certutil` via `brew install nss`.

I then run, `$ npm run develop -- --https`.

When I open `https://localhost:8000/` in Chrome I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` and in Firefox I get `Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`.

Any help on this would be appreciated.